# integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax^{2}}}{1+e^{x}} dx$ with a<0

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I've encountered the following integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax^{2}}}{1+e^{x}} dx\; \; with\; a<0$$

Is this integrable? I have seen similar topics asked before was solved with contour method but do not know whether, and how can contour method works for this one.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Mathematica gives: $$\mathscr{I}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{-\text{a}}}$$ Where $\Re\left(\text{a}\right)<0$

Comment: Can detailed proof or resources be provided Jan? and what do you mean by $R(a)<0$

Comment: Can I use Mathematica to get two following integrals by using Mathematica as well?   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^{x}} dx\; \; with\; a<0$$  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^{x}} dx\; \; with\; 0<a<1$$ Thanks for any information!!!

Comment: It means the real part of $\text{a}$, but the problem is: the integral is defined outside the region $\Re\left(\text{a}\right)<0$, so when $\text{a}\ge0$

Comment: integrate this using contour looks way too complicated. try this instead:
$$\frac{1}{1+e^x} + \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} = 1\implies\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax^2}}{1+e^x} dx = \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ax^2}dx\implies\cdots$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the integral converges since the integrand behaves like 
$
e^{ax^2}
$
as $x\to-\infty$ and like
$
e^{x^2(a-1/x)}
$
as $x\to+\infty$, and $a<0$.

Here is also a calculation which, however, does not use the contour method.
Let us split the integral as
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax^2}}{1+e^x}dx =
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{ax^2}}{1+e^x}dx+
\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{e^{ax^2}}{1+e^x}dx=I_1+I_2\,.
$$
Then, using the formula for the geometric series 
$$
I_1=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ax^2}}{1+e^{-x}}e^{-x}dx =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^\infty e^{ax^2-(n+1)x}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^\infty e^{ax^2-nx}dx
$$
whereas
$$
I_2= \int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{ax^2}}{1+e^{-x}}dx =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^\infty e^{ax^2-nx}dx\,.
$$
In the sum $I_1+I_2$ all terms cancel out except for $n=0$, thus
$$
I=\int_0^\infty e^{ax^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{-a}}\,,
$$
for $a<0$.

EDIT: In fact, as pointed out by Achille Hui in the comments, there is no need for geometric series
$$
I = \int_0^\infty e^{ax^2}\left( \frac{1}{1+e^x}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right) dx
=\int_0^\infty e^{ax^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{-a}}\,.
$$

Answer (score 1):

On the path of Brightsun and  Achille Hui (to achieve the computation)

$\begin{align}I&=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax^{2}}}{1+e^{x}} dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{ax^{2}}}{1+e^{x}} dx+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax^{2}}}{1+e^{x}} dx
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $y=-x$ in the first integral,

$\begin{align}I&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax^{2}}}{1+e^{-x}} dx+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax^{2}}}{1+e^{x}} dx\\
&=\int_0^1\left(\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}+\dfrac{1}{1+e^{x}}\right)e^{ax^{2}}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{ax^{2}}dx\\ 
\end{align}$

$a<0$, perform the change of variable $y=\sqrt{|a|}x$,

$\begin{align} I&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|a|}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}}dx\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{|a|}}
\end{align}$